# grounding rigid conduit (RMC)

Tags: electrical, grounding, electric-vehicle

Does a run of electrical rigid metal conduit (RMC) need to be grounded at both ends, if I am not using it as the circuit ground ?

For context, I am putting a electric vehicle charging station (EVSE) at the edge of a parking area.   I am using RMC since it need only be buried 6" deep (it never actually enters the parking area) and there are other underground utilities that I'm leery of disturbing.  The conduit will contain 2 hot wires (for 240vac to the EVSE) and a ground wire.

I'm connecting the RMC to the house wiring in a metal box in the crawlspace using this connector.   It's weather-proof, which I don't need, but it's unclear if it's rated for grounding.

[image]

At the EVSE end, I could thread the conduit into a weatherproof aluminum box ...

[image]

I note here [Grounding with conduit and cast aluminum weatherproof box](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194107/grounding-with-conduit-and-cast-aluminum-weatherproof-box) that it's questionable if this is rated for a grounding connection.   And I'd prefer to use a PVC box here.

Given the uncertainty about the grounding connection at either end, I'm glad I'm providing a ground wire.  I'm wondering if it's ok to use a PVC box at the EVSE end,  in other words, need the conduit be grounded at *both* ends ?   Is *either* ground connection adequate, that is, do I need another plan ?

Comment: If grounded at the beginning then grounded all the way.  Would need a ground connection at the plastic box if not using a ground wire(connect the EVSE ground to the RMC) and using the RMC as ground path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure UL514B requires the bushing to be rated to ground the conduit to a metal box that is rated for grounding.

Comment: I'm not using the RMC for ground path.   But the metal box (or boxes, if I use the weatherproof aluminum box at the EVSE end) need to be grounded.   Sigma doesn't seem to say if that hub is rated for grounding; I'll just have to assume it is.  I think this is a good reason to use PVC at the EVSE end; I don't need metal there for the ground path, and so better not to have a perhaps improperly-grounded metal box there (if the threads in the aluminum wx-proof box aren't a good grounding path).